# Google OAuth + Globo.com parou de funcionar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, auth

Nenhum cliente com email @globo.com está mais conseguindo acessar meus serviços via OAuth. Antigamente todos eles clicavam em "Login com Google", digitavam as credenciais da globo.com, e faziam login normalmente. Agora eles estão sendo redirecionados para o site do globomail, e não são mais redirecionados de volta.

Conversei com o suporte da globo.com, e eis a magnífica resposta:
"Obrigada por ter aguardado, A parceria da globo.com com os serviços Google (YouTube, Google+, Blogger entre outros) acabou será necessário trocar o email da globo para o email com outro domínio"

Isso significa que todos os meus milhares de clientes da Globo.com vão ser prejudicados? Vão ter que, um a um, trocar de conta, criar um Gmail, cadastrar uma senha, tudo isso?

Como resolver isso sem prejudicar todos os meus clientes?

Uso Rails + Devise + Omniauth.

Comment: Vejo que este problema está acontecendo com todos os grandes sites, como Quora, Descomplica, Soundcloud, enfim, todos os que usam autenticação via Google.

Comment: Com SO não está, acabei de logar com minha conta do Google normalmente.

Comment: O seu email é @globo.com?

Comment: Não, é gmail. Agora entendi seu comentário. Vc tá dizendo que quem tem email globo tb não consegue logar no Quora, Descomplica e Soundcloud, certo?

Comment: Isso, e antes conseguiam, pois o login da globo.com era via OAuth do google. Ou seja, todo mundo que tinha email @globo.com e usava ela pra fazer login com google perdeu todas as suas contas, em todos os sites em que fazia login.

Comment: Assim, de primeira, não vejo um problema de programação sendo exposto na pergunta...

Comment: Depende, se não houver uma resposta, não é um problema. Mas se houver algum fix no oauth do google que faz o login com a globo.com funcionar, então é sim um problema de Rails+Omniauth.

Comment: Então não seria o caso de começar *já* a procurar pelo fix? (com o código relevante)

Comment: Talvez. Eu não tenho ideia de um possível fix. Imagino que vou ter que pedir para cada cliente globo.com criar um email gmail.com, me passar o endereço desse novo gmail, pra eu fazer a troca manual. Mas isso não é viável.

Comment: O e-mail da globo.com mudou recentemente e parou de ser gerenciado pela Google, ou seja, não tem mais acesso ais serviços, talvez seu problema esteja aí e não diretamente na sua aplicação.